# React and apollo throwing 401 and Unexpected end of JSON with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

These are my queries / mutation that is executed after user submits form.

```
const ME_QUERY = gql`
{
  getCurrentUser {
      id
      email
      firstname
      lastname
      token
  }
}
`;

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
   mutation ($email: String! $password: String!) {
    token: login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      id
      email
      firstname
      lastname
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

And also here is a code for where the apollo client is setup.

```
const { REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL } = process.env;

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || sessionStorage.getItem('token');

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
});
```

Here is the errors the console is throwing. I've browsed for 20 days now, and haven't found a solution. The point of this code is to log user in. And these are the errors I get after pressing the login button.
[Console log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psy2j.png)

Comment: So first things first, your ME_QUERY shouldn't have brackets after the gql - that is definitely an issue.

Comment: I tested both the query and mutation in Postman and it works. The page goes blank if I do that and remove the brackets. It says: Uncaught GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "getCurrentUser".

Comment: It should be gql`
query getCurrentUser {
   getCurrentUser {
       ...
   }
}`

Comment: Thanks, tried that, however I'm still getting same errors in console as the image I linked in my post.